# Target encoding a categorical variable in a highly imbalanced dataset for binary classification

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, categorical-encoding, feature-engineering

I have a categorical variable, Industry, that has different values in a dataset that is over 400K datapoints. This dataset is highly imbalanced, the ratio of roughly 99/1. What I am doing is significantly undersampling the majority class to create a 50/50 dataset of 8000 datapoints (I definitely lost most of the training points because I need most of those to have a prediction made on them, though those are mainly from the majority class so I am not losing too many rare class data).

What I would like to do is mean encode this variable, Industry, against the target. For example, let's say I have NYC appear 1000 times in the training data, and 100 of them are in the positive class the value for datapoints with NYC will be 100/1000=.1 will be the value of this new feature, etc.

The problem is that because I am undersampling to make my dataset balanced, that skews this ratio by creating fake good ratios on the minority class because it now represents 50% of my training data rather then 1%. Hence, my training column will significantly overvalue the ratio compared to the testing set and will not help my machine learning algorithms at all.

What should I do in this case to create a good mean encoded ratio?

Comment: Have you tried modeling with the raw data and not downsampling?

Comment: yes, that gave me rather poor results because it had a rather hard time identifying the rare class. Now what I currently have is I am actually overfitting this variable that I am asking about because I basically used a computed ratio from the entire combined training & testing datasets but of course that is data leakage and not the right way to build a model

Comment: I suspect that this is enormously relevant: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)

Comment: well I am looking at other metrics besides accuracy to look at how well it did like the ROC Score, Confusion Matrix scores (aka specificity, sensitivity, etc)

Comment: Once you had fit the probability model, how did you use it to assign classes?  It's common to see people use a threshold of 0.5, under some belief that it is optimal, but this is ALWAYS a bad idea.  You need to tune your classification threshold in all cases.

Comment: @mkheifetz don't get fooled by the title of that question, the advice in Stephan's answer is much, much more general.  Please read it carefully.

Comment: That's how I assigned them yes, but I compared how the different values did using the predict_proba in scikit-learn. I think for example, everything that scores roughly 70% and above is very good, everything below sucks, the 50-70% score could be better in the sense that the success rate in that interval is lower then the average success ratio (success being one of the two outcomes) so what I currently have is (well I hope because I don't have anything in production) I think is somewhat good, but I know that I am currently leaking a variable that is useful in my data which I know is wrong

Comment: ok I will read it carefully. Regarding your other comment, what you are referring to as setting the probability to a higher threshold is the equivalent of just viewing the results of predict_proba, do I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have followed the good advice in the comments.  Why do you use downsampling? **It is most often used to solve a nonproblem**.  See [Why downsample?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122409/why-downsample)  and many of its answers. With only 400k rows memory shouldn't be a problem, if it is, get some better software. Their problem may be the use of accuracy, which is an *improper score function*,  see [Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359909/is-accuracy-an-improper-scoring-rule-in-a-binary-classification-setting).

Then the question about target (or mean) encoding. That is an idea from machine learning used with categorical variables with very many levels. Your variable *Industry* probably does not have that many levels, so you could try other ideas, like dummy variables with regularization, maybe try [glmnet](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html).  Glmnet uses sparse matrices so many levels isn't a big problem. If there is many levels, see some of the ideas here: [Principled way of collapsing categorical variables with many levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels).

Finally, if you still go for target encoding, see my answer here: [Strange encoding for categorical features](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398903/strange-encoding-for-categorical-features/414892#414892)

Comment: As others have said, any time you entertain downsampling you are fundamentally not understanding the true problem.